# Netlify redirects with language conditions not working as expected

Tags: redirect, netlify

i try setup redirects in `netlify.toml` but have some problems.

Expected behaviour:

- user with any browser language must be redirected to english version `.com/en/`;
- user with “ru” browser language must be redirected to `.com/ru/`.

Current behaviour:

- All users redirected to `/en/`, redirect to `/ru/` not working.

My netlify.toml (I inserted it whole so that there is more information):

```
[build]
  command = "yarn build"
  functions = "functions"
  publish = "dist"

[[redirects]]
  from = "/register"
  to = "https://domain.tld/register"

[[redirects]]
  from = "/login"
  to = "https://domain.tld/login"

[[redirects]]
  from = "/"
  to = "/ru/"
  conditions = {Language = ["ru"]}

[[redirects]]
  from = "/"
  to = "/en/"
```

PS. I tried setup redirects within `_redirects` file but it not worked at all.

Comment: Contrary to the local `netlify dev` server, the production server only does the redirect if the browser just sets one language: https://community.netlify.com/t/language-based-redirect-only-works-when-1-browser-language-set/4252